# If two columns partially match, replace third with awk

Tags: awk

File `a.txt`

```
chr:1:10539:A:C 10539 C A 0.545987 0.508902  0 0.36065 + 1
chr:2:13494:A:G 13494 A G 0.330493 0.0264746  0 0.733423 + 1
chr:7:13494:A:G 13494 A G 0.330493 0.0264746  0 0.733423 + 1
```

File `b.txt`

```
1 4972
2 4972
3 4972
7 4970
```

I am looking for a way to find partial match between `$1` of `a.txt` and `$1` `b.txt` and replace `$7` in `a.txt` with corresponding `$2` from `b.txt`.

So that output will look like

```
chr:1:10539:A:C 10539 C A 0.545987 0.508902  4972 0.36065 + 1
chr:2:13494:A:G 13494 A G 0.330493 0.0264746  4972 0.733423 + 1
chr:7:13494:A:G 13494 A G 0.330493 0.0264746  4970 0.733423 + 1
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include an example line for a chromosome number >9 and maybe X or Y? All your lines show single digit chr names, so people won't know that you can have 2-digit and even letters. That changes the approaches we can use for this.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` approach:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {split($1,b,/:/); $7=a[b[2]]}1;' b.txt a.txt 
chr:1:10539:A:C 10539 C A 0.545987 0.508902 4972 0.36065 + 1
chr:2:13494:A:G 13494 A G 0.330493 0.0264746 4972 0.733423 + 1
chr:7:13494:A:G 13494 A G 0.330493 0.0264746 4970 0.733423 + 1
```

#### Explanation

- `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}` : `NR` is the line number of the current input line and `FNR` is the current line number of the current file. The two will only be equal while reading the 1st file. Therefore, this will save the information from `b.txt` in the array `a` whose indices are the chromosomes from `b.txt` and whose values are the associated numbers. The `next` skips to the next line and ensures that the second block is not run for `b.txt`.
- `split($1,b,/:/); $7=a[b[2]]` : this will only be run for `a.txt`. First, it splits the 1st field on `:` into the array `b`. So the 2nd element of `b` will be the chromosome. Then, it sets the 7th field of the file to be whatever was stored in the array `a` for the chromosome stored in `b[2]` (this is what `a[b[2]]` means: `a[  b[2]  ]`).
- `1;`: this is awk shorthand for "print this line".